# Screen left in "Save button disabled" state after PXSetPropertyException

Tags: acumatica

I have written an extension for the SOShipmentEntry BLC with a FieldVerifying event linked to a udf on the Packages grid.  When the user enters a value, it checks to see if this value violates our business rules.  If it does, it triggers the following.

> throw new PXSetPropertyException(SWKMapadocMessages.Not_Prepped,
>   PXErrorLevel.RowWarning);

This works fine, however after that error is thrown if the user tries to save any subsequent changes, they get a "Error #299: The Save button is disabled" message and the save is cancelled.  The user has to refresh the screen to get back to a usable state.  Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon review of the customization, there seems to be an issue with the primary data view **Document** used as the **DataMember** for the custom ***MAPADOC*** tab. As explained in section **Providing Data for Controls** of the T200 developer training material, it is only possible to bind same data view to multiple container controls, if the data view is not specified as the **PrimaryView** for the datasource control. I believe, the issue with disabled **Save** button should be completely resolved after **CurrentDocument** is defined as the **DataMember** for ***MAPADOC*** tab instead of the primary **Document** data view.

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="MAPADOC">
    <Template>
        <px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="CstFormView10" DataMember="CurrentDocument" 
            SkinID="" Width="100%">
            <Template>
                ...
            </Template>
        </px:PXFormView>
    </Template>
</px:PXTabItem>
```

Aside from that, I also noticed  the `Actions.PressSave();` method invoked within the **FieldVerifying** event handler. To be honest, an event handler is never a good place to save changes to the database. An action delegate is a perfect place for that, but within an event handler, one should realistically never attempt to invoke the `Actions.PressSave();` method, since at that moment not all changes in DACs had reached the appropriate PXCache and might get lost because of execution of `Actions.PressSave();` being called.